# How to edit row height in the list?

Tags: list

How to edit row height in List?

Currently, in a view, I'm seeing that because of one column (which has lots of text in it), rows in the table are stretched vertically, making only one row to be visible per page.

Is there a way I can configure fixed row height? Text in that big column, can be viewed using scrollbar. 
Trying to insert Web Part->Script Editor hasn't been fruitful. It's inserting the script outside this table. Also "Edit this web part", has height and width settings, but that's for whole table.

[image]

Comment: Is the column must in your view ?

Comment: @Gaurravs, no it's not

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest some more advanced CSS so the user can see the full text on mouseover:

```
/* ListView - make Description fields a maximum width and height, and show full text on mouseover*/
/*.ms-itmhover is the TR row*/
.ms-vb2  .ms-rtestate-field{
    max-width:40em;
    max-height:2em;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.ms-vb2  .ms-rtestate-field:hover{
    max-height:none;
    background-color:whitesmoke;
}
```

Even more ways to deal with long text:

[How to Truncate a multiline column in a SharePoint List 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151473/how-to-truncate-a-multiline-column-in-a-sharepoint-list-2013)

Comment: This worked right off the bat, but it also killed my ribbon tabs. They no longer display at all (classic view).

Comment: Then increase CSS Specificity to only target DOM elements in the View Table

Answer (score 2):

You can fix the height of all multi line textbox whether it is in list view or in quick edit view.

Try below **css code** in list view

```
.ms-rtestate-field {
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 250px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Change the height & width as per your needs.

Apply this CSS in SharePoint master page if you want to to work for all multiline contents. If yo want it for a single page than add it to CEWP on specific page.

Take Reference from [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/148629/jquery-multi-line-textbox-scroll).

Answer (score 0):

Solutions suggested by Dikesh & Danny are the good approach.

I would suggest another easy approach. May be it can have some cons too but on a far side.

- Create a calculated column with some relevant name.
- Now add a formula `=LEFT([Description],25)&"…"`
- Now rename and change the display name to similar to your main column (Description column here)
- Not remove the original `Description` column from view, and add calculated column `Description` to your view.

This will make 25 characters to be displayed from the Description column to new calculated column. The View look better. Also for visualization column name will be same as we altered it.

Comment: Nice suggestion :) But it didn't work, as Calculated field doesn't entertain "Multi-line text" field in the calculation. It throws error "Output Type is not valid" (Selecting output type as "Singleline Text", as multiline text is not available in the option)